# If the $L$-series does not vanish

Tags: elliptic-curves

I refer to this paper http://wstein.org/papers/shark/shark.pdf

At the top of page 24, we are dealing with the issue where the $L$-series does not vanish for the case where $p$ is good and ordinary. The inequality in the second line is justified using Kato's Theorem 7.3, which is stated on page 22 and has the assumption that $p$ is a semistable. Can anybody explain why we may use Kato's Theorem 7.3 even though it seems like $p$ is in different cases?

Comment: "good" implies "semistable", so we are using a stronger hypothesis than the theorem we use, no ?

Comment: Probably, that sort of question is best asked to the authors directly :)